# Makefile - Finding arbitrary test directories

Tags: makefile, zend-framework2

I have a ZF2 application that I've setup to be built using a Makefile with various options. The issue at hand is that the `/vendors/` directory can contain an assortment of dependencies that are installed/updated via composer. Each dependency may, or may not contain unit tests, and the location of the tests are arbitrary.

When `make test` is run, I would like the Makefile to search through the `/vendors/` directory for any folders named `/tests/` and perform unit testing accordingly.

What would be the most optimal way to iterate through the vendors and locate any `/tests/` directories to be able to perform unit testing?

Comment: Just a side-note: It should not be necessary to unit-test the vendors. Since pretty much all of the Modules are run automatically over github via TravisCI. All running those tests does is: it costs you time and memory :P

Comment: This would be true if we weren't using our own internal vendors that are not public repos. Support for private repositories is still currently in closed beta and we need a stable solution immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`wildcard`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Wildcard-Function.html#Wildcard-Function) function:

```
LIST_OF_TESTS:=$(wildcard vendors/*/tests)
```

Comment: Is there a way to make the wildcard function recursive? Using `vendors/*/tests` doesn't work, but `vendors/*/*/tests` does work for some reason.

Comment: I do not know your exact project layout... I guessed/hoped you had a `vendors/*/tests` layout (where the `*` is used to match any vendor name). I do not understand want you mean with '_Is there a way to make the wildcard function recursive?_'... It is recursive and should find **all** matches.

Comment: I thought that it would be recursive, but by using `vendors/*/tests` alone, it did not succeed in finding any tests directories within the vendors. The directory structure is arbitrary, the `vendors` directory contains libraries and modules created by 3rd parties, so there's no definitive `tests` directory locations, hence my request for a recursive version. Using `vendors/*/*/tests` appears to work correctly though. Thanks for your help, very much appreciated.